# Checkboxes aren't visually updating when prop "checked" is programmatically toggled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's an example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mLsb7hed/2/).

When a checkbox is clicked, all of the surrounding neighbor checkboxes should toggle on or off.

It seems like it should work! Their "checked" prop toggles, but visually nothing happens.

```
n.prop("checked", !n.prop("checked"));
```

I'm surprised this is happening with prop() and not attr()
Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mLsb7hed/5/

Comment: You are wrapping object literal in `$()` ... not dom nodes

Comment: Try changing line 24, 25 to ```graph[pos].forEach((neighbor) => { n = $('#'+neighbor.id);```

Answer (score 0):

No, their checked prop doesn't toggle and the issue is not caused by using `prop()` over `attr()` (or vice versa).

The issue is on line 25. Selecting the DOM element with `n = $(neighbor);` does not do the trick, since on this stage each neighbor is a Checkbox object with 2 keys - `id` and `checked`.

To select the DOM element (and therefore, to actually trigger a change to it's value), use the id inside that object to select it by id inside the jQuery selector. Replace line 25 with:

```
n = $(`#${neighbor.id}`);
```

Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/superKalo/0thktq5f/

I hope this helps.